# Prove convergence of a sequence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a series of non-negative real numbers. 
Suppose $\sum a_n $ diverges.

Prove :

If  $\lim(na_n)$ exists (in $\mathbb R$ or $\infty$), then  $\sum \dfrac{a_n}{1+na_n}$ diverges.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Have you made any progress so far?

Comment: Yeah , i proved that if sum an diverges than sum1/1+an diverges too , couldn't seem how it could be helpful @abiessu

Comment: that does not seem true if you take $a_n=n^2$ then clearly $\sum a_n=\infty$ but $\sum \frac{1}{1+n^2}$ is convergent by comparison

Comment: If $\lim_{n\to\infty} n a_n$ is finite then there exists a number $x \in \mathbb R$ so that $x≥na_n$ $\forall n$, then $\frac1{1+na_n}≥\frac1{1+x}$ and since $a_n$ is non-negative:
$$\sum_n^N \frac{a_n}{1+na_n}≥\frac1{1+x}\sum_n^N a_n$$

Comment: @Spotty I think the second sum should be $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+na_n}=\sum \frac{n^2}{1+n^3}$, which diverges.

Answer (score 5):

- If $\lim na_n=0$ then clearly $a_n\sim \dfrac{a_n}{1+na_n}$ and the two series 
  $\sum a_n$ and $\sum \dfrac{a_n}{1+na_n}$ have the same nature. Thus  $\sum \dfrac{a_n}{1+na_n}$ is divergent.
- If $\lim na_n=\ell$ with $\ell>0$ or $\ell=+\infty$ then
  $\frac{a_n}{1+na_n}\sim\frac{k}{n}$ where $k=1$ if $\ell=+\infty$ and $k=\ell/(1+\ell)$ otherwise. But $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent, so $\sum \dfrac{a_n}{1+na_n}$ will also be divergent.